Order of Enigma's rotors does not increase total number of keys
I have a question about “order of rotors”. I read about Enigma but I do not understand this point. If the machine has 3 rotors, for example 1_2_3, so it has 26×26×26 total keys. If we change the configuration of these rotors, for example 1_3_2, it will not increase the total keys. So what does it mean of 6 × (26 × 26 × 26)? I really do not understand why we must multiply by SIX?

Duplicate of https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/55188/what-is-the-difference-in-exchanging-the-enigma-rotors-in-their-slots

Maybe you think the rotors are all wired identically? If all the rotors were identical then the order would be irrelevant, but they weren't.  You can see some examples here. An Enigma might come with three different rotors I, II, and III, and the six different orders in which you can put them into the machine would result in six different starting permutations.
