# Enigma machine Encryption steps

Tags: enigma

I am trying to build a simulated enigma machine.I am basing it off of this one https://www.101computing.net/enigma-machine-emulator/

I have setup the 3 rotors and I am having trouble understanding the rings and rotations. For example I have set the rotors to III,II,I with the 3rd rotors having a ring setting of AAB. If you enter and A then the output is a N. My simulator agrees with this.Then if you enter an A again the output is F. I followed my simulator through it process.

First

Rotor I (right most) rotates its keys to become JEKMFLGDQVZNTOWYHXUSPAIBRC. Then the A changes to a J.

Next

J passes through the next 2 rotors to end up as a C.

Finally

This C is then passed through Rotor 1 in the reverse direction to give the final output. The example outputs F. My simulator matches the output of the example up to here.How does C become F on Rotor 1 with position AAC in the reverse direction.Any help understanding how the rings and rotations affect the rotors would be appreciated.I have read [How does the ring settings of enigma change wiring tables?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/29315/how-does-the-ring-settings-of-enigma-change-wiring-tables) and I understand most of K Rossers answer until the final reverse output from the rotor.

Answer (score 2):

I think the steps on [these images](https://stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106a/cs106a.1164/handouts/29A-CryptographyChapter.pdf) will remove your confusion. Concentrate on the fast rotor and remember that only 3 rotors are rotating, the other 2 permutations are fixed - reflector and steckerboard.

[image]

Now, press $A$ on the keyboard and see the path. Watch the connections and the status of the fast rotor.

[image]

After this, the fast rotor will advance ( if necessary the medium and slow, too, here only medium and fast) and the re-entering $A$ will follow the below path.

[image]

The curial points are those;

- after a keypress, the permutation changes. Notice how the slow motor moves up and the wirings follow.
- The letter of the rotors indicates the position. At each point, the connection to the next rotor is kept ( the straight lines with bold connector).
- The internal wirings ( permutation ) changes the input and output at each step. There are 26 possible permutations for a rotor. This is the way Enigma confuse the data. Select a different permutation for every input. That is, however, is not enough to be secure.
- The below image is also may help to grasp the actual rotor motion.

[image]